# Why is LM2596 buck converter output current low when used as a mobile charger?

Tags: batteries, usb, battery-charging, buck, mobile

I have a LM2596 buck converter which is capable of providing 3 A and my input source, which is a transformer, is capable of providing 5 A.

[image: buck converter]

When I use the buck converter to charge my Android phone which can draw 2 A current from the AC charger, only 400 mA is flowing through my mobile phone. I have measured it using a USB tester device.

Can anyone help me to understand, or make it provide a higher current for mobile charging?

Comment: If the phone does not recognise the charger it will limit itself to a standard USB port's max. current of around 500mA.

Comment: Your issue isn't the power available, but rather convincing the phone to use more of it.  Questions on the *usage* of products (ie, the phone) are off topic here.  As a practical matter, see any of the various writeups on how phones determine charging power source capability; the one on the original Adafruit mintyboost wasn't bad.  There are also likely several previous questions here which this duplicates.

Comment: There are ways to put certain value resistors across the data lines to get more current. But that method won't get you more than 1amp.

Comment: Try a charger that SHOULD give higher current. If you CAN get more then you should be able to make this do similarly IF all is well. Some modules do not meet claims. Have you measured max available current from the converter? ALSO you need to show a circuit. We do not know what rectifier, filtering, voltage are involved and these and more are relevant. Use circuit editor in question screen to add a circuit (Ctrl-M).

Comment: Non technical discussion and copy of all other comments moved to chat. It would be nice if the seasoned and competent members could differ in a somewhat more polite manner. It may even help in reaching some intermediate point of view. Or not :-).  [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116717/discussion-on-question-by-rajesh-k-why-lm2596-buck-converter-output-current-is-l).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Phones do USB power negotiation to see what current the USB power source is capable of providing; your buck converter doesn't negotiate so the phone assumes a maximum, and this maximum is below what you expect.

My older Samsung mobile phone is happy when I short the data lines D+ and D- in my home-built charger's USB output, but this probably won't work for all phones.

If you want this to work for all brands and models, you will have to use a USB Charging Port Controller like the [TPS2514](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tps2514) (there are many others), but in view of the USB specification changes, and brands being idiosyncratic, even that may fail for some phones.

Here's [some more reading](https://obddiag.net/usb-power.html), in addition to the Mintyboost write-up Chris Stratton suggested. Note that the USB 3.x specs have some new ideas about all this.

Comment: +1 This is PROBABLY what is required. It would be easy and advisable to carry out the tests that I suggested in a comment to ensure that the supply is in fact capable of meeting the requirement. It's likely, but not certain, and as we do not know Vin that too may be a factor.